# yarn install in a docker container on an azure gcch vm sometimes fails with an EAI_AGAIN error when retrieving our own packages from azure artifacts

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, yarnpkg

### BLUF

`yarn install` on our Azure GCCH (Government) virtual machine sometimes fails with an EAI_AGAIN error when retrieving our packages from azure artifacts. But sometimes doesn't.

### Environment Setup

- Azure Government (US)
- Windows Server 2022: v21H2
- Jenkins: v2.414.3
- Docker: v24.0.7 (for our Jenkins Build Agents)
- Docker Containers: Various Windows Images
- Yarn: v1.22.19
- NPM: v8.19.2
- Node v16.18.0

### The Always Failing Scenario

I have a package.json with 3 packages pulled from our organization's Azure Artifacts on Azure Dev Ops. Our packages have some dependencies on publicly available packages on npmjs.com. When a build is kicked off the following actions are performed.

1. Jenkins fetches the latest code from the repo ✅
2. A Windows Docker container is spun up using hyperv isolation in which to run the job ✅
3. An .npmrc file is written with scope and auth info to connect to azure artifacts ✅
4. `yarn install --verbose` is executed ❌

Here is the output of `yarn install --verbose`. Successful requests to https://registry.yarnpkg.com/xxx have been removed for clarity.

```
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
verbose 0.7391124 Performing "GET" request to "https://myOrg.pkgs.visualstudio.com/Xyz/_packaging/Xyz/npm/registry/@Xyz/filter/-/filter-19.0.0.tgz".
verbose 3.4757218 Performing "GET" request to "https://myOrg.pkgs.visualstudio.com/Xyz/_packaging/Xyz/npm/registry/@Xyz/header-footer/-/header-footer-20.0.1.tgz".
verbose 3.5398324 Performing "GET" request to "https://myOrgpkgs.visualstudio.com/Xyz/_packaging/Xyz/npm/registry/@Xyz/usage-tracking/-/usage-tracking-9.6.0.tgz".
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
verbose 15.0789971 Performing "GET" request to "https://myOrg.pkgs.visualstudio.com/Xyz/_packaging/Xyz/npm/registry/@Xyz/filter/-/filter-19.0.0.tgz".
verbose 15.7042555 Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN blahblahblobprodeus2150.blob.core.windows.net
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26)
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://myOrg.pkgs.visualstudio.com/Xyz/_packaging/Xyz/npm/registry/@Xyz/header-footer/-/header-footer-20.0.1.tgz: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN blahblahblobprodeus2150.blob.core.windows.net".
```

### Working Scenarios

There are some scenarios where this seems to always work.

| Scenario | Description | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Just One Package | Only one Azure package in package.json | Always Works |
| Only Public (npmjs.com) Packages | Only npmjs.org packages in package.json | Always Works |
| Using NPM | Swap yarn for npm | Always Works |
| Old Jenkins Env. | **Very** similar setup but this virtual machine is on our org's network rather than in Azure Government | Always Works |

### Other Notes

I ran a few DNS resolution tests from different environments using nslookup, Resolve-DnsName, and ping for myOrg.pkgs.visualstudio.com. The address can be resolved in all environments including from within the docker container with the sole exception of ping.

| env | nslookup | Resolve-DnsName | ping |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jenkins-in-azure[host] | ✔ | ✔ | ✖ - Request Timed Out. Note: The first reply succeeded with correct IP address |
| jenkins-in-azure[container] | ✖ - Server: Unknown | ✔ | ✖ - Request Timed Out. Note: The first reply succeeded with correct IP address |
| jenkins-on-prem[host] | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |
| jenkins-on-prem[container] | ✖ - Server: Unknown | ✔ | ✔ |
| personal-laptop[host] | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |
| personal-laptop[container] | ✖ - Server: Unknown | ✔ | ✔ |

The assumption is that the `ping` operation is blocked in our org's Azure firewall in front of our Azure Government Cloud.

### Stumped

We're stumped.

One suggestion that has been proposed is that there is an issue and/or some protective measure between Azure US Government (location of our new Jenkins server) and Azure Commercial Cloud (location of Azure Dev Ops) that is these issues or outright blocking the requests. We're engaging Microsoft Support but we also wanted to engage the broader community.

Have you encountered this? Have you heard of any network issues between Azure US Government and Azure Commercial? Any suggestions?

Comment: The EAI_AGAIN error is a DNS lookup timeout error that indicates a network connectivity problem or a proxy related issue. It appears that it's not able to resolve the hostname `blahblahblobprodeus2150.blob.core.windows.net`. As it works sometimes, the issue could be caused by the DNS server is overloaded, or the network connection is slow or unstable. If you try again after the error reported, will it work then? Maybe you can change the network for a check.

Comment: Repeated runs when I have more than 1 azure artifacts package always fail. If I just have one package, yarn install works. I find that behavior quite odd. I tried the same setup outside the Azure Gov network and it works fine as noted in the description above.

Comment: Not commenting as an answer yet, but I was able to resolve the issue by explicitly setting the DNS of the docker container to Google's public DNS by adding `--dns 8.8.8.8 --8.8.8.4` to the docker run command. For an unknown reason the host OS's DNS doesn't always resolve address in azure artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing! it should be caused by the DNS resolution as per your fix. You can post it as answer as it should be the simplest way to fix it.